# android sherlockactionbar overflow text color

Tags: android, overflow, actionbarsherlock

I'm using SherlockActionBar and I'm currently customizing it. So far it's good until I've reached the point to configure the overflow in the action bar. I want to set the text color to white but no matter what I try I can't change the color. How can you do that?

```
<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar</item>
        <item name="background">@drawable/action_bar</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/CustomActionBarTitleTextColor</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/CustomActionBarTitleTextColor</item>
        <item name="actionBarSplitStyle">@style/CustomActionBarSplitStyle</item>
        <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/action_bar</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/action_bar</item>
        <item name="actionBarSplitStyle">@style/CustomActionBarSplitStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarSplitStyle">@style/CustomActionBarSplitStyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarDivider">@color/separadorMenu</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@color/separadorMenu</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/CustomActionBarTitleTextColor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PopupMenu" parent="style/Widget.Sherlock.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/action_bar_dropdown</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@color/separadorMenu</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
    </style>
```

Any hints on how can I set this overflow text white?

Comment: I think you can change the stacked background but not the textColor

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`<style name="ActionBar.YourActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">`